# WINDOWS 10 - Error Windows Update 10 = Error in phase " SAFE_OS " with the operator error with " BOOT "

Tags: boot, windows-10

For days I tried several ways to install Windows 10 .
With Windows Update I have always an error
and with the media creation tool microsoft I have this message:
" The installation failed in SAFE_OS phase with an error when BOOT operator "
with this code : 0xC1900101 - 0x20017
Having tried everything I do not know what to do ...
Can you help me please ?
Thank you

PS: I migrated my OS with the software "Paragon migrate OS to SSD" from my hard disk to my SSD. Maybe I have this errors because I did this....

Comment: After you migrated to SSD, did you check your authentication was still valid? [Right click My Computer, get Properties, look for the 'Genuine' notice near the bottom] Mine wasn't after the same Paragon Migrate OS to SSD & I had to fix that first, then the upgrade to Win10 went as planned.

Comment: "Starting to see threads where people who moved their OS to an SSD and it is not the original "Device 0" where the OS was installed is the issue." http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-installation-error-0xc1900101-0x20017/5bdf6fe0-11c7-470d-a7ab-fcda4765be24?page=2

Comment: Apparently, this problem is not terribly unusual.  I've seen the same thing and there are a group of people on several forums complaining as well (although no one seems to have a solution yet):
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/4997/t/19643586?pi239031352=1
http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/migrate-ssd-w10-cant-upgrade-to-ssd.378535/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, probably caused by paragon software.
The migration tools seems to have damaged or altered bootsector or bcd in efi.
Using the steps described here:
http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/12/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-in-windows-8/
for correcting the two things, the installation works now.

I hope this other people....

Comment: Please include the full information necessary to solve the problem in your answer, citing the link as a reference. Links break all the time and we're trying to be a question and answer site, not a link farm.

Answer (score 0):

That response won't load just now.  I also had what appears to be the same problem.  After trying all the other suggested approaches, I succeeded by replacing the SYSTEM volume:
get an administrater-level command prompt  (I booted via Windows 10 usb stick, selected "repair" option)

run diskpart
list volume
select volume x  (the volume labeled "SYSTEM" mine was about 340 Mb)
format label=SYSTEM
exit

then
bcdboot c:\windows

that's it.  reboot, run setup to install from the usp stick, and voila!

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft Community:

Disable (preferrably uninstall) your Antivirus utility before attempting the upgrade.

Make sure your machine name is simple no periods or hyphens or dashes.

Restart a few times then try again.

Disable General USB Devices (example - Smart Card Reader).

If you are using a SCSI hard disk, make sure you have drivers available for your storage device on a thumdrive and it is connected. During Windows 10 setup, click the Custom Advanced Option and use the Load Driver command to load the appropriate driver for the SCSI drive. If this does not work and setup still fails, consider switching to a IDE based hard disk.

Perform a clean boot, restart then try again.

If you are upgrading using the .ISO file, disconnect from the Internet during setup, if you are connected by LAN (Ethernet) or Wi-Fi, disable both then attempt setup again.

If you are updating through Windows Update, when the download reaches 100% disconnect from the Internet LAN (Ethernet) or Wi-Fi then proceed with the installation.

If that does not work, try using the .ISO file to upgrade if possible.

If you are connected to a domain, switch to a local account.

If you have any external devices attached to the machine, disconnect them (example, gaming controllers, USB keys, external hard disk, printers, non-essential devices).

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-troubleshoot-common-setup-and-stop-errors/324d5a5f-d658-456c-bb82-b1201f735683)

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem: couldn't update Windows 10 to anniversary edition / creators edition with this error: The installation failed in SAFE_OS phase with an error when BOOT operator, error code : 0xC1900101 - 0x20017. I has used the paragon migrate os to ssd tool as well.
After fixing the Windows boot loader with Neosmart Easy Recovery Essentials for Windows 10 everything worked.

Comment: I cannot warn people enough.  If you use Neosmart Easy Recovery Essentials, it will take actions, and cause you to be unable to boot into your Windows installation.  This personally happened to me, it was a nightmare to fix, and their support were unable to help.