# Cannot upgrade Windows 7 Pro 64bit to Windows 10 on Dell Vostro 3460 (dual boot with Kubuntu)

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-10-upgrade, kubuntu

I am trying to upgrade Windows 7 Pro 64bit in my dell vostro 3460 to Windows 10, however when the instalation procedure is reboots the machine for the first time, it loads Windows 7 again and the setup program gives me the message

> The installation failed in the SAFE_OS phase with an error during BOOT operation

and the error codes 0xC1900101 - 0x20017. I have searched the internet for solutions, like updating drivers on the dell website, but nothing works. I do not have an encrypted HDD or similar. I have also tried with a minimal boot and disabling all unnecessary devices in the BIOS (like USB devices and card readers, everything !!). Nothing works.

The only thing different is that i have a dual boot system, Windows 7 and Kubuntu, using Grub as boot loader, but according to the internet, that should not be a problem.

Any ideas on what else can i try to do to get the upgrade going?

UPDATE: This question is not answered by the suggested question in the duplicated tag. The problem was not other that GRUB. Windows 10 installation seems to have problems with grub being the boot loader. I used Windows recovery mode to uninstall grub from the MBR and reinstall Windows 7 boot loader and once i did that, Windows 10 installed flawlessly.

Comment: I assume you have disconnect all non-essential USB devices and configure a minimal boot configuration and tried the upgrade?  In other words any program or device not require for the system to boot should be temporarily disabled in the registry.  [Background](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arvindsh/2015/07/07/error-0xc1900101-0x20017-upgrading-to-windows-10-build-10162/)

Comment: I disconected an usb mini wifi, disabled internal wifi and bluetooth devices, which seem to be connected via internal usb. The machine has also an internal backup disk of 32gigas, which also seem to be connected via usb. Should i disable it too ?

Comment: Please read my comment again.  Any device that is not required for the system to boot and be functional (mouse and keyboard) should be disabled.  You are trying to eliminate any device or service or application that might be causing this error.

Comment: I did a minimal boot and also checked that the actual system is detected as a genuine (OEM) Windows 7. However, the error persists. It just won't install Windows 10. The answers given in the original [question](http://superuser.com/questions/952384/windows-10-error-windows-update-10-error-in-phase-safe-os-with-the-opera) are not useful for my case

Comment: Solved my problem. Windows 10 installation had problems because GRUB was the boot loader installed in the MBR. See my updated question